# Refusal of compensation raise / demotion?

Tags: promotion, raise, compensation, demotion

Is there an HR perspective I could ask for by refusing a raise or again requesting a demotion?

I was just informed I am being awarded a raise of several thousand dollars. This came as quite a shock as my last two reviews were 'needing improvement'. Those reviews just happened to occur after reporting fraud and waste, as well as several violations of both company policy and ethical boundaries. One of the individuals involved in those questionable activities stated that I was "too expensive" while creating a work environment to get me to quit.

When I questioned the timing and the whys and hows of this windfall, I received more of a wishy-washy 'company baseline improvement' and 'median trend'- both which are legit concerns in a competitive industry.

My current title is expected to create wealth of several million- by cost savings, business opportunities- basically work I used to do *easily* until I was dropped. I asked for a discussion about getting a demotion since they were not providing the jobs that I could meet the minimum requirements for my rank. That discussion went no where.

For over two years I have felt beyond worthless, betrayed (literally and figuratively), and slandered with no ability to defend myself due to restrictions imposed by HR and Legal. The organization as a whole has evolved a minuscule amount but the threads of the rot that permitted those actions and those that covered for it are still very much alive.

I've looked deep here and only come across a few examples of refusing to take raises- most advice is to 'say thank you' and move on. This is not a tax-bracket situation.

I'm just so very confused and fearful I'm being set up. And I just don't have the trust to ask to speak with anyone in HR (again) after the last set of go-arounds.

Thank you.

Comment: Always post your country.

Comment: Was this person you reported responsible for doing your performance review?

Comment: @Donald No however they are 'aware', mainly because said statements swirling. I do not know the level of stock they put in them but once exposed it becomes hard to unsee.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to turn down a raise and promotion?

Comment: "This came as quite a shock as my last two reviews were 'needing improvement'."  Have you improved since those reviews?

Comment: Did you think that perhaps this could be a consequence of your previous actions? One branch of the company might want to sweep the fraud and unethical behaviors under the carpet, while other might prefer it to be known and acted upon before it creates a bigger scandal / legal liability. Your manager might be of the former camp (thus the bad reviews), yet someone else forced them to give you the raise you would have 'normally' deserved (or even you would be entitled to, and there is a company risk that you could sue for that!).

Comment: It may even be more complex, with the later indirectly awarding you for what you did using some kind of "excuse" so that you get the raise _despite_ opposition in your department.

Comment: @Ángel No, I hadn't considered that. Current leadership I have 100% belief and trust in. I *know* these people, and I can not for one moment entertain the possibility they would have reacted the same. Until you said this though I never considered the possibility. Thank you. Silly 1st world problems, right? Pity they've come so close to wrecking my life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is all about how to make the current job work. I agree with other posters that you're not crazy if you think you're hearing danger signs.  But this wasn't a "stay or go" type question, this was about strategies in the current position, so that's what I'm answering.

### The Raise

In a big company, it's not crazy that they would give a raise to a poorly rated employee and be all handwavy about it.  Sometimes the wheels of a big company move in ways that make very little sense for the individual.  For example, if they found you grotesquely underpaid and they thought the optics looked bad for some reason... or if the boss has every intention of getting rid of you, but wants to make sure the *position* is funded competitively for the next new hire.  I wouldn't waste a lot of time trying to read much into it, unless you have a friend in HR in that particular company who can help you read the tea leaves in that environment.  There's just too many different options to consider.

Take the raise.  If it comes with no strings attached, don't be more of a corporate difficulty for trying to refuse more money for the same job.  If there ARE strings attached - like a title change or extra responsibilities - you have more of an option of saying "no, I don't want the work, so I don't want the money" - that may still be a no-go with this company.  For example, in cases where employees are offered a raise for doing newly added oncall support work - the thing is that the company needs people who will do the work, so refusing the raise & the extra work can often be a condition where they say "find a new job" - but this is (I think) a different situation than what you describe.

### The Demotion

Yes.  Poorly rated employees do sometimes have the option to take a demotion, and you're well within your rights to ask.  The rules are highly variable, but I do know of cases where this has happened.  The most common case is personal reasons - that someone has impediments in health or family life that means they can't meet the expectations of the current role - but could plausibly meet the expectations of a less demanding role.

Things to look for to see if this is an option:

- Are you above the bottom rung of the ladder in your discipline.  Ie, is that you are a "Your Job, Level N" and there is a version of "Your Job, Level N-1" that people around you have.  It's better if actual people actually have the job, because it's easier to prove it's a viable option.
- Is there an opening for a "Your Job Level N-1"?  Does your team have such people?  It's a harder move if the people with this role are really only working for a different boss several organizations away... you may need to figure out how to swing a transfer to that boss.  Tricky in a tough political situation.
- Is there a demonstrated need for a "Your Job Level N-1"?  Meaning, are there others working in that role who are not expected to ever be promoted to your current role?  (case in point, an internship role is often one that is seen as purely temporary, while a mid level role may be fairly permanent)

That said - you also have to ask yourself -- will the demotion actually fix the problem?  If they had spurious reasons for the low rating, and you suspect this is political -- they will have spurious reasons for hating your performance in the lesser role, and then you will be one rung lower and in the same unpleasant spot.  Changing teams or business units or companies may be more helpful in this case.

NOTE - also - taking a demotion like this is a fairly permanent/terminal affair.  If it's done for an easy to understand life reason (having a baby, taking care of a seriously ill family member, being seriously ill, etc...) - then the company may be willing to promote you again if the personal situation changes.  But if this is totally because they say you don't have good performance, and you want to get to a safe spot where your performance will be considered OK - figure that you won't get an opportunity in this organization to try for that more ambitious role ever again.  They will, unfortunately, remember you as the person that couldn't hack it - however false that may be.

### Raise then Demotion?

Yep.

*How do you take a raise and then a demotion?* - easy - you just do it.  Accept the raise, and start working the politics for the demotion.  The demotion doesn't happen overnight - there's usually a bit of discussion and paperwork and such.  That probably means your paycheck gets weird, you have a few months of the pay with the raise, and then you go into the new role with less money.  Presumbably, whatever your new role salary will be - you are still benefiting from whatever competitive assessment led to the raise.

Comment: Thank you. I have, and did, work at the level (and above) for years with no problems. The issues started when I pointed out certain... ethical and fraudulent behaviors. I lost, obviously. And by only feeding me work below my level I could never attain the results needed to justify my current wage grade.
This is a lot of food for thought and I'm going to need to think on it. Just 'leaving' is so... not centric to many parts of the country. There is planning and strategy here I need to think over. So thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 7):

You have two reasonable choices: Get a job elsewhere, or take the raise. Anything else is unreasonable. Even if you decide today you'll get a new job in six months, your cards are much better if you have a raise in between.

Answer (score 5):

Do not refuse a raise. Refusing cannot possible help your situation but it can make it significantly worse, since you are signaling "I'm done here". And you get less money that way too.

However DO refuse any strings that are attached to the raise. If you need to sign any document to accept the raise, make sure that you read them very carefully and consider having them checked by a labor lawyer. If you don't like what's in there, don't sign it. If that cost you your raise, so be it.

So take the raise and keep looking.

Comment: Thank you; I had not thought about the implications of tacitly acceptance. I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a country with reasonable worker protections you are likely protected from them manufacturing a situation where they need to let you go.  Creating a situation like this is known as constructive dismissal and is treated as without cause dismissal.

I would accept the raise with the following language:

> Based on assurance that this would keep me in line with median trends
> and not make me an overpriced outlier in terms of wages, I will accept
> this raise.  If my understanding of the basis for this raise is flawed
> please let me know.  Thank you.

This protects you from future agruements that they are overpaying you as it's putting back on them that you believe what they are saying and if this isn't the case that you want further discussion of the raise.

All this said if you are in a place with "at will" employment you can be removed for no reason at all, so you may as well take the raise and get the benefit of that rather than getting removed at a later date for another reason with no raise.